# jQuery append divs text into two containers

Tags: jquery, html, performance, each

I want to get the text of certain divs, enclose them in a span and append them to two different containers. I am trying to do it as efficiently as possible but I think I am overcomplicating things.

HTML in the beginning:

```
<div id="container">
  <h3 class="text">aaa</h3>
  <h3 class="text">bbb</h3>
  <h3 class="text">ccc</h3>
</div>
<div id="appendHere1"></div>
<div id="appendHere2"></div>
```

HTML how should be in the end:

```
<div id="container">
  <h3 class="text">aaa</h3>
  <h3 class="text">bbb</h3>
  <h3 class="text">ccc</h3>
</div>
<div id="appendHere1">
  <span class="someClass">aaa</span>
  <span class="someClass">bbb</span>
  <span class="someClass">ccc</span>
</div>
<div id="appendHere2">
  <span class="someClass">aaa</span>
  <span class="someClass">bbb</span>
  <span class="someClass">ccc</span>
</div>
```

My first attempt which works but calls `.append()` in each iteration of the each loop is:

```
var $appendHere1 = $('#appendHere1');
var $appendHere2 = $('#appendHere2');

$('h3.text').each(function() {

  $appendHere1.add($appendHere2)
    .append('<span class="someClass">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');

});
```

I have tried different attempts using [jQuery.map()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
// Doesn't work:

var text = $('h3.text').map(function() {
  return '<span class="someClass">' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
})

$('#appendHere1, #appendHere2').append(text);

// Doesn't work:

var $text = $();

$('h3.text').each(function() {
   $text.append('<span class="someClass">' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
})

$('#appendHere1, #appendHere2').append($text);

// Doesn't work:

var text = $('h3.text').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
})

$('#appendHere1, #appendHere2').append(text.each(function(){
    return '<span class="someClass">' + this + '</span>';
}));
```

**How should I use jQuery.map() or jQuery.each() to achieve this in an efficient way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `each()` loop and `append()`

```js
$('#container > h3').each(function() {
  $("#appendHere1, #appendHere2").append($('<span class="someClass"></span>').text($(this).text()))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h3 class="text">aaa</h3>
  <h3 class="text">bbb</h3>
  <h3 class="text">ccc</h3>
</div>
<div id="appendHere1"></div>
<div id="appendHere2"></div>
```

You could also use `map()` to build an array and then use `join()` to convert it to string and append it to your divs.

```js
var html = $('#container > h3').map(function() {
  return '<span class="someClass">'+ $(this).text()+'</span>'
}).get()

$("#appendHere1, #appendHere2").html(html.join(''))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h3 class="text">aaa</h3>
  <h3 class="text">bbb</h3>
  <h3 class="text">ccc</h3>
</div>
<div id="appendHere1"></div>
<div id="appendHere2"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is almost what I tried in the question, isn't it a bad idea calling append inside each?

Comment: please ignore my edit, I thought he wanted to transfer classes along with the text... my bad

Comment: @ Maher Fattouh no problem.